# How to bypass a simple countdown with tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have this countdown javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var seconds = 5;
var timer;
function countdown() {
    if(seconds >= 0) {
        document.getElementById('dl').innerHTML = seconds;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = '<a href="http://mylinkhere.link"><img src="/button.png"/></a>';
        clearInterval(timer);   
    }
    seconds--;
}
timer = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
</script>
```

How do I create a function to run in tampermonkey for this specific website in order to decrease or even instantly bypass it?

Comment: You probably should clarify what the goal is. You can bypass the interval in many ways, but it looks like in your code, after the countdown has ended, it shows a link. Is the goal to get this link faster? Or simply remove the countdown altogether?

Comment: Show the link faster, that's it. But as mentioned, it needs to be a tampermonkey script

Comment: If the page code is *really* as shown, you can use `window.seconds = 0` in conjunction with `@grant none`.

Comment: Could you show me in pratical how would that be? I'm really, really, really noob with Javascript and I have no clue how to do it in tampermonkey. NVM, I did it =P. I don't know if that is the best way to do it, but it solved the problem. Is there a faster way maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Newscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @author       Username
// @match        http://mylinkhere.link/download/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    window.seconds = -1;
})();
```